# how can I completely disable the horizontal scrolling system

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, line-breaks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSly3.png)when I one line too long, my full editor get horizontally large & scrollbar comes (like 1st image)

[image: image 1, my vscode][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rzx9.png)

I want long lines will break in multiple short lines

(like 2nd image)

[image: image 2, how I want my editor]

Comment: There should be a `word wrap` option in your VS preferences. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/how-to-manage-word-wrap-in-the-editor?view=vs-2022

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We don't debug images here.

Comment: Press Alt+Z shortcut on your keyboard

Answer (score 2):

You have to turn on the WORD-WRAP Feature in Visual Studio Code.
There are 2 ways to do this:

1. By using the View menu (*View** → Toggle Word Wrap)
2. By using the Keyboard Shortcut
   Windows/Linux: ALT + Z
   Mac: ⌥ + Z

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an appropriate answer given the plain language of the question:

Download the app called "[Multitouch](https://multitouch.app)" on MacOS, and go to Settings, and chose the option "Disable horizontal scroll".

It will "completely disable the horizontal scrolling system".